# highlight.js code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use the highlight.js but it didn't work

i work like they say in the website but i don't know what's wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/default.css">
<script src="js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
 <title></title>  
 </head>
```

//test the code

```
 <pre><code class="html"><input type="text" name="test" id="test" value=""></code></pre>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.7.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

the result in the browser is a normal textbox not the code how to solve this ?

Comment: what are you trying to highlight?

Comment: Any live demo to show your problem?

Comment: @DanyalImran i put it under test code

Comment: @WangYudong the problem like i say it didn't show the code it run the code show the output of the code

Comment: Have you included your .css and .js file correctly? Any error shows in browser console? If you have a live website, it's more easier for us to resolve your problem.

Comment: @WangYudong i put the all the code here i include the css and the js files like you see above and my page is not online the code i put it above is all the code in my page

Comment: Initialize after dom loads.

Comment: @WangYudong Do i need to include a jquery to my page and what is this jquery ?

Comment: @suyesh Do i need to include a jquery to my page and what is this jquery ?

Comment: Yes, obviously you should include jquery before highlight.js, download from here https://jquery.com

Comment: @LuninRoman i put this jquery https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js but also didn't work

Comment: @LuninRoman and i try the link above for the css and javascript and also didn't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suyesht/nr3n1gvf/   See here its working.

Comment: @suyesh how it's work i try to put an html code and he run the code or a php code i try to put <?php echo"test";?> he give me test but he should give <?php echo"test";?>

Comment: https://vangarsushil.medium.com/how-to-use-highlight-js-ddf2e5123a

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason your HTML code is not treated as code by `highlight.js` is because the browser parsed the HTML tags. The solution is to replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` to escape angle brackets. If you included your .js and .css file correctly, make these change will help:

HTML version:

```
<pre><code class="html">&lt;input type="text" name="test" id="test" value=""&gt;</code></pre>
```

PHP version:

```
<pre><code class="php">&lt;?php echo"test";?&gt;</code></pre>
```

BTW, no need to use jQuery if you include .js file in HTML `<head>`. The script will run after the page loaded.

Comment: and what about if i want to put a php code or a javascript code like this <?php echo"test"; ?> and i put a jquery code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js put also doesn't work

Comment: i tried your update query put your update answer put your update work for html not for php and javascript like should be highlight.js

Comment: @mhmd Sorry I didn't catch it. Do you still have any problems after trying my method? You can upload your test project somewhere and it will help to find  where the problem is.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00398961054453455823                    http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73088552547311510957       you can download this file and see it and th jquery i put above

Comment: @mhmd Which part do you want to highlight? PHP only or `<div>` plus PHP code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124011/discussion-between-wangyudong-and-mhmd).

Comment: https://vangarsushil.medium.com/how-to-use-highlight-js-ddf2e5123a

Answer (score -1):

In a case if you're using **php on backend** you can use php function **htmlspecialchars** to convert special symbols programatically.

```
<pre><code class='language-php'>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars( 
'<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="">' );
?>
</code></pre>
```